# FileZilla breaks rbash and scponly chrooting

Tags: shell, ssh, scp, filezilla, chroot

I've got a stock Ubuntu install on a server and I'm trying to only allow certain users to scp files to their own home directories. I read up on `rbash` and `scponly` for doing this job, made the required changes to `/etc/passwd`, and verified that they were working correctly when connecting directly in a terminal via ssh or scp.

However, when FileZilla logs in as any of these users, it's able to prance around ls'ing and cd'ing to its heart's content, and I can't figure out why.

I've ensured there isn't an FTP daemon running on the server (therefore, as far as I know, forcing FileZilla to connect via SFTP/SSH and load the shell specified for the user), and beyond that I've got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably not disabled/chrooted the SFTP.

I assume you have followed some obsolete chrooting guide. Nowadays, when the SFTP is by default a built-in feature of the OpenSSH `sshd`, a shell-level restrictions/chrooting does not apply to the SFTP anymore.

If you want to disable the SFTP, just remove the `Subsystem sftp` directive from the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Though it breaks FileZilla, as it does not support the SCP protocol.

If you want to keep the SFTP, you have two options:

- Change the `Subsystem sftp` to run the subprocess `/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server` instead of the `internal-sftp`. This should make the `scponly`/`rbash` restrictions apply.
- Nowadays, you should better use a built-in chrooting functionality of OpenSSH instead of the `scponly`/`rbash`.
  See the `ChrootDirectory` directive:
  https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config

Comment: Thanks. I seem to have gotten the restriction to take effect by changing Subsystem sftp to /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server, but Filezilla now closes the connection with exitcode 1 (essentially a perms thing from the looks of the docs) -- I guess it's not as tolerant of rbash as I was led to believe? Using ChrootDirectory %h is similar -- "Server unexpectedly closed network connection".

Comment: First, I'd suggest you forget about `scponly`/`rbash`, make sure you roll back all configuration changes you made for these. Focus only on `ChrootDirectory` solution. Also make sure you use `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` directive, instead of path to `sftp-server`. See for example [How to setup a SFTP server with users chrooted in their home directories?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49271/how-to-setup-a-sftp-server-with-users-chrooted-in-their-home-directories)

Comment: If you still get the errors after following the instructions, take a look in the syslog/OpenSSH log. I believe the errors has nothing to do with FileZilla. Chrooting should be transparent to SFTP client.

Comment: I was eventually able to sort it out by chowning the restricted users' home directories to root, and creating a subfolder in there which they were allowed to write into. Not the world's most elegant solution but neither is FTP in general, and it does the job. Your instructions were helpful, thanks!